# How I can two subtotals summarize in the table SQL Server Managment Studio 2014?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, datatable, subtotal

I have an SQL query which returns `orderid` and `quantity` ordered for all orders with an `orderid >= 11075` and `orderid <= 11076`:

```
select orderid, quantity 
    from [order details]
where ((orderid >= 11075) AND (orderid <= 11076))
```

My ResultSet is:

[image]

But I need subtotals in my table. I need to generate a control-break report that provides the total quantity for order numbers 11075 and 11076. `COMPUTE` and `COMPUTE BY` don't work in my version of SQL Server. How can I implement this?

Such a table like:

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>orderid</th>
    <th>quantity</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11075</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11075</td>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>11075</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Sum</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>=======</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>42</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11076</td>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11076</td>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11076</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Sum</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>===========</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: this looks like a presentation issue. Should do it in your frontend application and not in `SQL Server`

Comment: @Squirrel I don't have web-application. This is example of a table that I want to output when run query.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate the results you want using `GROUPING SETS` and some conditional unpivoting

```sql
SELECT
  v.orderid,
  v.quantity
FROM (
    SELECT
      orderid,
      quantity = SUM(quantity),
      grouping = GROUPING(quantity)
    FROM YourTable t
    GROUP BY GROUPING SETS
      (
        (orderid, quantity),
        (orderid)
      )
) t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
        (NULL, 'SUM', 1),
        (NULL, '====', 2),
        (NULL, '', 4)
    ) v(orderid, quantity, ordering)
    WHERE t.grouping = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      CASE WHEN t.grouping = 0 THEN t.orderid END,
      CAST(t.quantity AS varchar(20)),
      3
) v
ORDER BY
  t.orderid,
  t.grouping,
  v.ordering;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=48ec45704008484c49a04ac37f210fa3)

To create the table you want, you could use `FOR XML`, however it would be pretty complex, and probably easier done in another language.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by others, this seems to be more of a presentation issue.

However, you can build a query that produces a result similar to what you want using `ROW_NUMER()` and [`GROUP BY ROLLUP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#group-by-rollup):

```
  select orderid
       , case when orderid is null then'grand total' else isnull(try_convert(varchar,rn),'subtotal') end as rn
       , sum(quantity) as quantity
    from (
           select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by orderid order by orderid) as rn
             from order_details
            where ((orderid >= 11075) AND (orderid <= 11076)) 
         ) tmp
group by rollup (orderid, rn);
```

This will also include a grand total row at the end.

| orderid | rn | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11075 | 1 | 10 |
| 11075 | 2 | 30 |
| 11075 | 3 | 2 |
| 11075 | subtotal | 42 |
| 11076 | 1 | 20 |
| 11076 | 2 | 20 |
| 11076 | 3 | 10 |
| 11076 | subtotal | 50 |
|  | grand total | 92 |

Note: if you already have some kind of other column that is unique within each `orderid`, like for instance a unique `id` column,  you could also omit the `ROW_NUMBER()` and use that column instead of `rn` in the `GROUP BY ROLLUP` directly.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=c74b0934099daecbe2c7991003ab1c51).